# Graph search for askubuntu

Tags: feature-request

I think it will be very good if there was any graph search like Facebook graph search for this web site. Some examples can be like this:

1. Questions by 'john' answered by 'joe' comments by 'nick' votes >=10
   which refers to question asked by 'john' and one of the answers belongs to 'joe' and his question voted more than 10 and also 'nick' comments on that.

So I there some thing like that? May be not but I think it would be interesting if we have that in stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's http://data.stackexchange.com where you can build SQL queries against site data.